# Sending Email through Javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I've been trying to send an email using the javamail api. The debugs from the smtp server (smtp.live.com) are showing 550 5.3.4 Requested action not taken; To continue sending messages, please sign in to your account.

It seems to create the message fine but doesn't allow it to send. Any ideas why?

```
  try
     {
     // Setup properties for e-mail server
     Properties props = System.getProperties();
     props.put("mail.smtp.host", mConfig.getEmailHost());
     props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
     props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
     props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

     // Get a Session object
     Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new MyAuthenticator());
     session.setDebug(true);
     Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

     // Create message
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

     // Add the to/from fields
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mFromAddr, mFromName));
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mToAddr));
     if (mCCAddrs != null)
        {
        for (int i=0; i<mCCAddrs.length; i++)
           message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(mCCAddrs[i]));
        }
     // Add Subject
     message.setSubject(mEmailSubject);

     // Setup multipart message for including the attachment
     Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

     // Create message body
     BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
     messageBodyPart.setText(mEmailBody);
     multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

     if (mAttachmentName != null)
        {
        // Create message attachment
        BodyPart messageAttachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageAttachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDatasource(data)));
        messageAttachmentPart.setFileName(mAttachmentName);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageAttachmentPart);
        }

     // Send message
     message.setContent(multipart);
     transport.connect(mConfig.getEmailHost(), mConfig.getEmailUser(), mConfig.getEmailPassword());
     transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
     transport.close();
     }
  catch (Exception ex)
     {
     ex.printStackTrace();
     throw new Exception("Failed to send e-mail: " + ex.getMessage());
     }
  `
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to actually include some credential information in your authenticator. The server is indicating to you that it doesn't allow sending emails anonymously.

```
new MyAuthenticator()

       ^-------- fill this with some credentials
```

Note that, unless your mail server has some special requirements, that it is normally sufficient to use the [standard password authenticator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/PasswordAuthentication.html):

---

**Edit/Update**

I took a closer look at your error message, based on your feedback. It looks to me like Hotmail is requiring you to login to the account you have setup and verify it, before using it to send emails. You may want to login using a web browser and checking for an activation link from them, prior to using the account.

Comment: I already have,    private class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator
      {
      public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
         {
         return new PasswordAuthentication(mConfig.getEmailUser(), mConfig.getEmailPassword());
         }
      }

Comment: Did you debug your `mConfig` values for `emailUser`, `emailPassword`. Are they present when the authenticator is being created?

Comment: I've changed my session to Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
         protected PasswordAuthentication
         getPasswordAuthentication() {
         return new PasswordAuthentication(mConfig.getEmailUser(), mConfig.getEmailPassword());
         }
         }); I still get the same error.

Comment: @AC3112 - Did you verify that `mConfig.getEmailUser()` and `mConfig.getEmailPassword()` have valid values prior to the authenticator being created?

Comment: Interesting, its possible your account requires activation then. Please see edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the Below Code.

```
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import javax.mail.Address;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

    public class TestJavaMail {
    private String SMTP_PORT = "465";
    private String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
    private String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String contentType = "text/html";
    private Properties smtpProperties;
    public TestJavaMail(){
    initProperties();
    }

    private void initProperties(){
    smtpProperties = new Properties();
    smtpProperties.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
    smtpProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    smtpProperties.put("mail.debug", "true");
    smtpProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT);
    smtpProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port",
    SMTP_PORT);
    smtpProperties.put ("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
    SSL_FACTORY);
    smtpProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback",
    "false");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String to= "sendToMailAddress";
    String from ="sender email_id";
    String pwd = "Sender password";
    String subject= "Java Mail";
    String body= "Testing to write Doc on java mail.";
    send(to, from, pwd , subject, body);
    }
    TestJavaMail.java Continued…
    public static void send(String to, final String from
    , final String pwd, String subject,String body){
    TestJavaMail tjm = new TestJavaMail();
    try
    {
    Properties props = tjm.getSmtpProperties() ;
    // -- Attaching to default Session, or we could start
    a new one --
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication
    getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(from, pwd);
    }
    });
    // -- Create a new message --
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
    InternetAddress.parse(to, false));
    // -- Set the subject and body text --
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setText(body);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    // -- Send the message –
    Transport.send(msg);
    System.out.println("Message sent OK.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    public Properties getSmtpProperties() {
    return smtpProperties;
    }
    public void setSmtpProperties(Properties smtpProperties) {
    this.smtpProperties = smtpProperties;
    }
    }
    }
```

Hope it Will Help you.